# Nginx redirect http to https with dynamic host

Tags: nginx

My question is generic. I am setting up Nginx config file which should support different domain name. How should I redirect `http` to `https` with should support different domain name?

Here my configuration.

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    test-server;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         test-server;
      // ssl configurations
}
```

the result should be

```
curl -I http://awesomedomain.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 08:30:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: https://awesomedomain.com/
Connection: keep-alive

curl -I http://helloworld.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 08:30:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: https://helloworld.com/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Use `$host` variable instead of `$server_name`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I if hit with `$server_name` it redirects to `https://test-server`. it should be `https://domain.com`

Comment: Have you read my comment?

Comment: @AlexeyTen. Thanks it works :)